# Highcharts doesn't display data

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I'm a newbie in using Highcharts.  I created a sample ASP.NET MVC application to create a line graph out of a json data returned from my controller into my view page.  Also, I used ajax to get the data for the chart via success callback function.

This is the structure of the data (sample 4 rows of type TagTimeValue in a List)

```
private List<TagTimeValue> GetTagTimeValues()
    {
        var tagTimeValues = new List<TagTimeValue>
        {
            new TagTimeValue { ID=1, Name="CDT158", Value="23.9483", Time="04/01/2017", Good="true", Questionable="No", Units="vol", Substituted="not"},
            new TagTimeValue { ID=2, Name="CDT158", Value="24.1183", Time="04/02/2017", Good="true", Questionable="No", Units="vol", Substituted="not"},
            new TagTimeValue { ID=3, Name="CDT158", Value="25.2383", Time="04/03/2017", Good="false", Questionable="yes", Units="vol", Substituted="not"},
            new TagTimeValue { ID=4, Name="CDT158", Value="25.6713", Time="04/04/2017", Good="false", Questionable="yes", Units="vol", Substituted="not"}
        };

        return tagTimeValues;
    }
```

This is the method invoked by ajax call

```
public ActionResult UpdateTrend()
    {
        var values = GetTagTimeValues();
        return Json(values, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The script that invoke `UpdateTrend()` via ajax call in `Index.cshtml`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/home/UpdateTrend",
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false
        }).success(function (dataChart) {
            var Xaxis = [];
            var dataSeries = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < dataChart.length; i++) {
                var items = dataChart[i];
                var XcategoriesItem = items.Time;
                var seriesData = items.Value;

                Xaxis.push(XcategoriesItem);
                dataSeries.push(seriesData);  
            }

            console.log(dataSeries);
            getChart(Xaxis, dataSeries);

        }).error(function (er, xhr, e) {
            console.log("Error: ", er, xhr, e);
        })
    });
```

And, the `getChart` function

```
function getChart(Xaxis, dataseries)
    {
        var myChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Alarms/Events Chart'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '{y}%'
                    }
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                title: {
                    text: 'Time'
                },
                categories: Xaxis
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                }
            },
            series: dataseries
        });
    };
```

where it renders the chart to the `<div id="container" style="width:100%; height: 500px;"></div>` with an `id` of container.

Based on the scripts, I want my chart to have an x-axis of Time and, y-axis of value as series.  But, when I run the application, there's no data displayed (screenshot below).

[image]

I also checked the json data in Google's chrome `console` panel, which I can see an array of `Time` (x-axis) and `Value` (series) parsed successfully.
[image]

Is there a missing configuration in my chart that wouldn't allow to display the series?  Or, does my chart script is wrong?

I googled for similar issues, and I found heaps of possible solutions but, quite confused which one should I follow.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe you're making one series per data point, rather than a single series with multiple data points. What highcharts expects is something like `series: [{ name: 'some name', data: [1, 2, 3, 4]}]` whereas you're providing `series: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]`

Comment: @Rob thanks for your response.  So, you're saying Highcharts doesn't accept one series per data point?  If that is the case, then in my function `getChart`, it should be something like this `series: { name: 'some name', data: dataseries }`, where `dataseries` is still an array of values.

Comment: It accepts that, if that's what you provide it; my point being is that you're using the API incorrectly; `series` isn't a set of data points, it describes the series in more details. Take a look [here](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series#1) at the documentation. If you want one series per data point; that's fine - but you still need to provide each series with an array of data (even if that array contains one element). So yes, I believe your example in your comment should work

Comment: @Rob, I have changed `series` to something like this `series: [{ name: 'series 1', data: [23.9483, 24.1183, 25.2383, ....]}]` and the chart displayed.  Thank you also for sharing the link on Series | Highcharts documentation.  I also noticed that when an element of an array is a string in a `series`, the line graph doesn't display.

Answer (score 0):

Since posting this question, I don't have knowledge in Highchart.  After 2 weeks of researched and using the library, I have learned basic configuration that will display data in the chart.  For the benefit of other developers who seek help or just starting using Highchart, this is how I implemented it.

ajax call to fetch data from the server and plot onto the chart

```
    function plotTrendData(data)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/your url goes here/',
        data: { requestData: data },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data)
        {
            if (data.length > 4) {
                prepareChartData(data);
                if (myChart === null) {
                    plotChartData(dataSeries, xTitle);
                }
                else {
                    addChartSeries(dataSeries, xTitle);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

function that prepares chart data (`dataChart` paramater contains the `json` data)

```
    function prepareChartData(dataChart)
{
    if (dataSeries.length > 0) dataSeries = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dataChart.length; i++)
    {
        var items = dataChart[i];
        var xDate = +moment(items.Time);
        var seriesData = parseFloat(items.Value);

        dataSeries.push([xDate, seriesData]);
        xTitle = items.Name;
    }
}
```

function that add series onto an existing chart (for multiple series chart)

```
    function addChartSeries(dataSeries, xTitle)
{
    myChart.addSeries({
        name: xTitle,
        data: dataSeries
    });
}
```

And, of course function that create the chart onto your `div` element with an id of `container`

```
    function plotChartData(dataseries, xtitle)
{
    myChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            zoomType: 'xy',
            panning: true,
            panKey: 'shift',
            plotBorderWidth: 1
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'My Sample Chart'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'left',
            itemDistance: 10,
            borderWidth: 0,
            itemMarginTop: 0,
            itemMarginBottom: 0,
            padding: 20
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    format: '{y}'
                },
                allowPointSelect: false
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            labels: {
                rotation: -60,
                format: '{value:%d %b %Y %I:%M}',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '9px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            },
            crosshair: {                  
                enabled: true
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            gridLineColor: '#DDDDDD',
            gridLineWidth: 0.5
        },
        tooltip: {
            positioner: function () {
                return {
                    x: this.chart.plotLeft,
                    y: this.chart.plotTop
                }
            },
            useHTML: true,
            pointFormat: '<small><font color="{series.color}"><strong>{series.name}</strong></font>: <strong>{point.y}</strong></small><br/>',
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 8px">{point.key}</span><br/>',
            xDateFormat: '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S',
            shared: true,
            valueDecimals: 2,
            followPointer: true,
            shadow: false,
            borderWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)'
        },
        series: [{
            name: xtitle,
            data: dataseries
        }]
    });
}
```

The above script and configuration displays the data into my highchart.  Isn't that amazing!